# Cross-origin image load denied despite appropriate permission

Tags: apache, three.js, textures, cors

I'm trying to run the following example http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_geometry_cube.html on my local apache and I just replace the following line :

```
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('textures/crate.gif');
```

by

```
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/textures/crate.gif');
```

I've added the directive allowing cross-domain request in my enabled site configuration, which looks like :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
    <Directory /var/www>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

The response header of request confirms that header directive is taken into account :

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:725
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Tue, 08 Jan 2013 12:41:32 GMT
ETag:"40ee7-61b-4d2c62fdc4cf4"
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Last-Modified:Tue, 08 Jan 2013 12:35:55 GMT
Server:Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

Nevertheless I get the following error : **Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy** on chromium console.

Did I miss something in my apache configuration ?
Thanks in advance !

---

**Edit** :
Here are the request and response headers for the document (containing the ThreeJS code) :

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8Accept-Charset:UTF-8,*;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,de;q=0.2
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost
Referer:http://localhost/tests/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/12.04 Chromium/20.0.1132.47 Chrome/20.0.1132.47 Safari/536.11

Response Headersview source
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, PUT, POST, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:725
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Thu, 10 Jan 2013 17:52:48 GMT
ETag:"40f8f-61b-4d2f2d858c1d0"
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Last-Modified:Thu, 10 Jan 2013 17:52:40 GMT
Server:Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

And here the request and response headers for the wanted image on mrdoob.github.com :

```
Request URL:http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/textures/crate.gif
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

Request Headers
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:UTF-8,*;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,de;q=0.2
Host:mrdoob.github.com
Origin:http://localhost
Proxy-Connection:keep-alive
Referer:http://localhost/tests/cors_texture_loading.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/12.04 Chromium/20.0.1132.47 Chrome/20.0.1132.47 Safari/536.11

Response Headers
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:max-age=86400
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:67585
Content-Type:image/gif
Date:Thu, 10 Jan 2013 17:52:48 GMT
Expires:Fri, 11 Jan 2013 17:52:48 GMT
Last-Modified:Fri, 28 Dec 2012 00:07:28 GMT
Proxy-Connection:keep-alive
Server:GitHub.com
Via:1.1 proxy.thecorporateproxy.fr:2598 (squid/2.7.STABLE9)
X-Cache:MISS from proxy.ign.fr
X-Cache-Lookup:MISS from : proxy.thecorporateproxy.fr:2598
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After reading [Wikipedia CORS article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) and [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), it seems that I misunderstood how CORS works.

Actually, my script, whose origin is `http://localhost` tried to access an image hosted on mrdoob.github.com. So, I set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `"*"` for my local server configuration. But actually, it's mrdoob.github.com server which should be configurated whith this, not my local server.

Since I don't have access on mrdoob.github.com server configuration, it's seems that CORS can't help me in this case to load my texture stored on another server than my local one.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` header:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE"
```

Comment: I just set it but nothing change.

Comment: Does your server allow OPTIONS requests? There could be a preflight step that is being denied.

Comment: I don't think that a preflight request is being sent. Actually there are only 3 **GET** requests sent according to the chromium network tool. Nevermind, how do I know if my server allow OPTIONS request ?

Comment: Do you have a sample of the request headers that are being sent to the server?